# How to view javadoc tooltip in Eclipse, if there's a warning marker on that line?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Raw javadoc markup is hard to read, but Eclipse has a handy ability to render the javadoc you just wrote in a tooltip. However, if there's a warning, it shows the warning tooltip. How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the intended behavior is for you to solve the error before writing the javadoc any further. If you want to a quick way to get around it, you can attach the class javadoc by attaching the source in eclipse by:
>
> select Window -> show view -> javadoc (or alt + shift + q, j).
>
> then in the javadoc view, right click -> open attached javadoc (or shift + F2), this will display the javadoc of the class in the internal browser of eclipse.

Comment: `Shift + F2` only works when external javadoc is attached

Comment: You need keep only the second part of the answer

Comment: That intention does not make sense, since to fix the error, you would most likely want to see the javadoc (or at least the method signature).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by pressing [F2]

Comment: Oh, you are right. You can press Shift + F2 to open the full javadoc or use the javadoc-view

Comment: This only works with an attached external javadoc and really isn't the same as the popup/tooltip.